# How do I check a value of an SQLite table in the background, and send a notification every hour?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I've been trying to find out how to do it, maybe using an IntentService, but I'm not sure that's the correct way for what I want to do.
Can someone at least point me in the right way?

Comment: Use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do stuff in background you can use [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or simply a Thread.

To do work in a loop, you can use [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), while the most common one will be [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Each one of the above got its own advantages and disadvantages. Read more about them to find what you need.